# How to join multiple tables to get names of employees who earn more than their manager?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created two tables:

```
create table DEPARTMENTS 
( 
    dept_id  number,  
    dept     varchar2(50) not null, 
    mgr_id   number,
    location varchar2(50),  

    constraint pk_departments primary key (dept_id)  
);

create table EMPLOYEES 
(  
    emp_id         number,  
    fname          varchar2(50) not null,
    lname          varchar2(50) not null,  
    email          varchar2(50),
    phone          number,
    hired          date,
    job_id         varchar(20),
    salary         number(7,2),  
    commission_pct number(4,2),  
    dept_id        number,  
    grade          number,

    constraint pk_employees primary key (emp_id),  
    constraint fk_employees_dept_id foreign key (dept_id) 
        references DEPARTMENTS (dept_id)  
    constraint fk_employees_grade foreign key (grade) 
        references SALGRADE (grade)  
);
```

How go I get names of employees who earn more than their managers given that the mgr_id is in table departments and the employee is in employees table and they are linked by dept_id ?

I found that 'self-join' is needed. But this case is a bit difficult since referencing dept_id is needed to refer to the mgr_id then compare it to the emp_id and create join ?

Comment: Yes, you need a double JOIN.

Comment: ok i will try that.

Answer (score 1):

For better clarity and self understanding, using ANSI joins:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT E.SALARY AS MANAGER_SALARY, D.DEPT_ID AS DEPT_ID 
    FROM EMPLOYEES E 
    INNER JOIN 
    DEPARTMENTS D
    ON E.DEPT_ID = D.DEPT_ID) 
MGR_DET 
INNER JOIN 
EMPLOYEES EMP
ON MGR_DET.DEPT_ID = EMP.DEPT_ID 
where EMP.SALARY > MGR_DET.MANAGER_SALARY;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with three joins.  Start with the `employees` table, match to `departments` to get the manager.  And then match back to `employees` using the manager.

This looks like:

```
select e.*, em.salary   -- or whatever columns you want
from employees e join
     departments d
     on d.dept_id = e.dept_id join
     employees em
     on em.emp_id = d.mgr_id
where e.salary > em.salary
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer with implicit joins:

```
SELECT E1.* FROM EMPLOYEES E1, DEPARTMENT D, EMPLOYEES E2
WHERE E1.DEPT_ID = D.DEPT_ID AND D.DEPT_ID = E2.DEPT_ID AND D.MGR_ID = E2.MGR_ID
AND E1.SALARY >= E2.SALARY;
```

Here the employee E1 is the employee whose salary is greater than that of his department manager.
To find that, we join the employee table E1 and department table D to get on `dept_id` and then fetch the `mgr_id`. Now the next step is to find the employee with the same ID as the `mgr_id` of the department. Hence we again join it with another employee table E2 on `emp_id`. Finally we compare the salary of employee e1 and the manager (employee e2).

Answer with explicit joins:

```
SELECT E1.* FROM EMPLOYEES E1 JOIN DEPARTMENT D ON E1.DEPT_ID = D.DEPT_ID
JOIN EMPLOYEES E2 ON (D.DEPT_ID = E2.DEPT_ID AND D.MGR_ID = E2.MGR_ID)
WHERE E1.SALARY >= E2.SALARY;
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but ... This is obviously an homework assignment, by just giving the poster the answer he will not learn anything IMO.

Comment: Besides, the teacher will not be impressed by those comma separated, implicit joins...

Comment: Okay I will edit my answer and try to explain and also include explicit joins